# AJAX response is not processed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've created several AJAX calls succesfully, but somehow the following simple AJAX test does not work. I have two variables which are set with the input of a form (this works). Let's call these variables input_1 and input_2. I want to pass these inputs to a php file, the php file processes it and returns something. Finally, the response is set in a JS variable. For now I place the response in a DOM element, to see if the AJAX call is succesfull. Unfortunately it's not.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var input_1 = 'abc'; // this is input of the form
var input_2 = 'def'; // this in input of the form

function generate_content(x,y)
{

$.ajax({
          url: "create_response.php",
          type:"get",
          data:{firstvar:x, secondvar:y} 
        }).success(function(response){
            document.getElementById("temp-id").innerHTML=response;
        });         

}   

generate_content(input_1, input_2);

</script>

<p id="temp-id"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

And the php file create_response.php:

```
<?php

$var1=$_GET['firstvar'];
$var2=$_GET['secondvar'];

echo $var1;

?>
```

So, I expect input_1 (='abc') to be displayed in the p-tag called 'temp-id' because

- input_1 is send to create_response.php as firstvar
- create_response.php gets firstvar and sets it as $var1
- $var1 is echoed, which is the success function of the AJAX
- response of success function is displayed in p-tag 'temp-id'

But it's not.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: What is displaying? If nothing then likely parse or syntax error

Comment: Is the HTML/JS code you showed the entire contents of the file? It looks like you're trying to use jquery, but have not included jquery.

Comment: Your code does not follow [JS code style standards.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

Please get in the habit of following these styles.

Comment: Open the Console in your browser's developer tools. Read the error messages. You've got some pretty obvious problems (like never defining `$`).

Comment: nothing is displayed...including jquery didnt solve it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no `success` method on [`$.deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/), perhaps you should try `.then` or `.done`

```
function generate_content(x,y) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "create_response.php",
      type:"get",
      data:{firstvar:x, secondvar:y} 
    }).then(function(response){
        document.getElementById("temp-id").innerHTML=response;
    });         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your function as a `success` property on the settings object within the ajax call, instead of using it like a method as you are currently.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "create_response.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{firstvar:x, secondvar:y},
    success: function(response){
       document.getElementById("temp-id").innerHTML=response;
    }
});
```